# Vector space and diffeomorfizm

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

1)Why there are dont exist diffeomorphism between $2sin(x)\partial{x}$ and $sin^2(x)\partial{x}$?
2)How to find all of the vector fields which commute with the vector field $\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}$ and 2$\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}-\frac{\partial}{\partial{y}}$. I think that with $\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}$ commute all the fields on the form $f(x,y)\frac{\partial}{\partial{x}}+g(x,y)\frac{\partial}{\partial{y}}$ which the partial derivative with respect to the variable is equal to 0.

Answer (score 0):

2) Let's $L_a$ and $L_b$ be the corresponding differential operators for the vector fields. So there's the remarkable result about your problem, namely: vector fields commuting iff $[L_a, L_b]=0.$ Just use it and the solution will come immediately.
1) Are there in $\mathbb{R^1}$ or?..

Comment: In $\mathbb R_1$, yep

Comment: You need to look at the pictures. What we can say about these vector fields in $\mathbb{R^1}$? (look at directions).